# Trying to merge two collections together in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parsing, meteor, collections

I have two collections in my application that are parsed from two separate json files. I have inserted data from the two files into separate collections. The collections have corresponding numerical ID's and I want to match them up in a new collection. For example: the ***postmeta*** collection has a `post_id` value and the ***posts*** collection has a corresponding `ID`.

To explain this further here is a simple collections example. One thing to note is that there are over 730 collection posts and although there are matching ID's they are not sorted so when I view them they don't match each other.

The ***posts*** collection example:

```
{
  "_id": "kTeQxenYZcQfPiaYv",
  "ID": "44",
  "post_content": "Today we talked about the letter Hh..."
}
```

The ***postsmeta*** collection example:

```
{
  "_id": "otEGQYxvv6MkCABST",
  "post_id": "44",
  "meta_value": "http://www.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/snackTime.jpg"
}
```

What I would like to do is parse through the collections and take for example ***posts*** collection where the `ID` matches the ***postsmeta*** collection. Once I find a match I want to insert the collections content (`post_content` & `meta_value`) into a new collection.

Here is all my code so far.

**lib/collections/posts.js**

```
Postsmeta = new Mongo.Collection('postsmeta');
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
```

**server/publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish('postsmeta', function() {
  return Postsmeta.find();
});

Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
  return Posts.find();
});
```

**server/main.js**

```
Meteor.startup(() => {

  var postsmeta = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('postsmeta.json'));
  var posts = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('posts.json'));
  var length =  postsmeta.length;

  for(x=0; x < length; x++){

    Posts.insert({
      ID: posts[x].ID,
      post_content: posts[x].post_content
    });

    Postsmeta.insert({
      post_id: postsmeta[x].post_id,
      meta_value: postsmeta[x].meta_value
    });   

  }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's refactor your code a bit. We'll build the `Postsmeta` collection first and then jointly create the `Posts` and `PostsCombined` collections. Since `Postsmeta` will already exist we can just search inside it to find matching documents.

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  const postsmeta = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('postsmeta.json'));
  postsmeta.forEach(doc => {
    Postsmeta.insert({ post_id: doc.post_id, meta_value: doc.meta_value }); 
  });

  const posts = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('posts.json'));
  posts.forEach(doc => {
   const post = { ID: doc.ID, post_content: doc.post_content}
    Posts.insert(post); // omit if you don't need the uncombined collection
    const metadoc = Postsmeta.findOne({post_id: doc.ID}); // essentially a JOIN
    if (metadoc) post.meta_value = metadoc.meta_value; // guard against no matching meta
    PostsCombined.insert(post);
  });   
});
```

The following IDs are not present in your [postsmeta data](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/9311b7d89bb8b4cfd82f38f3b47d3466/raw/77e9365c095c0ce33d5c1d83c0335347befde3e4/blob.json):

```
   ["56", "322", "521", "563", "583", "608", "625", "671", "707", "708",
    "711", "713", "754", "758", "930", "1068", "1126", "1235", "1237", "1238",
    "1239", "1246", "1249", "1256", "1263", "1355", "1375", "1678", "1680", "1763",
    "1956", "2107", "2121", "2148", "2197", "2249"]
```

Comment: On this line `Posts.insert({ ID: doc.ID, post_content: doc.post_content });` I get a error saying `'('` ***expected***. Not sure why?

Comment: In my editor the above is the error I get and in the app itself I get this error `server/main.js:30:64: Unexpected token, expected ,`

Comment: added missing braces

Comment: Thanks getting closer, now I am getting a error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta_value' of undefined`

Comment: That means there is no matching `metadoc` for that particular post. Are you sure there's a 1:1 match between all documents in your original json files?

Comment: hmm, the post_id and the ID match, but not in the right order. If that makes sense.

Comment: Here is the two json files in a gist. https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/d2aa107fba0ecc2901b39c25d94bd844/raw/41884f81c3500dce853fef4eaa465595c316c20a/blob.json & https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/9311b7d89bb8b4cfd82f38f3b47d3466/raw/77e9365c095c0ce33d5c1d83c0335347befde3e4/blob.json

Comment: The order shouldn't matter as the `Postmeta` collection will get fully populated before the `Posts` one.

Comment: Ok, I am a little confused. When you say that there may not be a 1:1 match, are you saying that the two json files may not have two ID's the post_id and the ID that match each other, the numerical number. Because when I do a find and search for a (ID) number in each json file I do find matches, I obviously haven't checked every (ID) for a match, so if there are some that don't match does that mean it wont work. Hopefully this is clear enough.

Comment: See guard against that.

Comment: Sorry I know I am supposed to keep that comments to a minimum, but what does ***see guard against that*** mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to put the collections together for consultation? because the insertion is correct for two different collections.

**Tip one**

If it is for query use the "[find().map()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/)", if you are using mongodb, within the function it will return the values ​​of each row of the first collection and soon you can call the other collection and check the id of the collection and return a JSON or Array of what you need. I do not pretend to do it that way, but it's a way of putting the two collections together.

**Best solution**

The correct way is not thinking as if noSql was a relational database like the other postgres, mysql and etc ... think that it is a dynamic bank, where in the same collection you can have everything you need at that moment, so I think You create a new collection that would be the junction of the two, when save saves the data in this other collection, which would be the query collection, and in that it would weigh less the query and until it would return the data faster, but suppose a 5x more faster than the above example ...

I hope I have helped, any questions or doubts I will be here. Hugs!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congrats for having the courage to post an answer as a new user. Just a recommendation: try to include actual code in your answers along with the explanation of why you're recommending a particular approach. Please keep trying!

Comment: sorry I did not know it was to give a direct answer, without what is in doubt I have to study more about it and improve its knowledge, but for this reason I asked exactly what I wanted, it was a query or insert, in the case of insert when you save it already brings the id automatically, I'm still marked -1 with my answer being correct lol, but okay, sorry for responding ...

Comment: I don't know who down-voted your answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: grateful, I will update my response to a clearer and quicker understanding context, thank you very much for the patience and competence